# use values to call factory's function in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

Im trying to call the factory function from a controller using values but im getting a TypeError
**Controllercode**

```
   $scope.onButtonHovered = function(event){
console.log("event.descriptorName "+ event.descriptorName);
            console.log("SERVICES[event.descriptorName].name "+ SERVICES[event.descriptorName].name);
            $scope.service = SERVICES[event.descriptorName].name;
            $scope.btnOptions = $scope.service.buttonOptions();
            }
```

**prints:**
event.descriptorName HOME

SERVICES[event.descriptorName].name homeService

VM92009 angular.js:13642 TypeError: $scope.service.buttonOptions is not a function

**Services:**

```
angular.module('ht.constants').
    value('SERVICES',{
                        HOME : {name : 'homeService', descriptor : {}},
CONTACT: {name : 'contactService', descriptor : {}},
                    });
```

**factory:**

```
     angular.module('ht.home').
        factory('homeService', [ HomeService]);
    var homeService= {}
        function HomeService() {
     homeService.buttonOptions = function(){
                if(homeData==null)
                    init();
                return homeData;
            }
return homeService;
    }
```

Im trying to call multiple services using one controller, while printing im getting the expected but when i append the same with a factory function im getting the error.
Thanks for the help

Comment: what is the `event`?

Comment: button click custom  event

Comment: convert `value()` to a service instead and return the appropriate other service from there. Would be like a master service and you wouldn't need to inject the others in controller

Comment: if i couldnt get the answer in a day or two, ill change value into a service.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$scope.service = SERVICES[event.descriptorName].name;
```

to this

```
$scope.service = SERVICES[event.descriptorName];
```

Comment: i wonder how that helps SERVICES[event.descriptorName] gives HOME not the desired homeService. And i did gave it a try but still the same error.
VM197634 angular.js:13642 TypeError: $scope.service.buttonOptions is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.btnOptions = eval($scope.service).buttonOptions();
```

eval did the trick.
Thanks everyone for helping me out.